# Using Laravel auth::attempt with hashed password

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

This seems like a really easy one but I really can't figure it out. I want to use `Auth::attempt($credentials)` in **Laravel 4** but with a password that has already been hashed (since it's an API). It works when I send the unhashed password, but I don't understand how to tell Auth to “not hash” the given password.

Quick “demo”

What works:

```
Auth::attempt([Request::getUser(), Request::getPassword()]);

curl --user username:notHashedPassword localhost:8000/api/
```

What doesn't work:

```
Auth::attempt([Request::getUser(), Request::getPassword()]);

curl --user username:$2y$08$xo7HpxFyeF2UKHOYs/e localhost:8000/api/
```

Are there any arguments I could pass to `Auth::attempt()` that would tell it to use it as it is instead of trying to rehash it (as I think it does)?

Comment: Glancing over the code: either define your own implementation of `UserProviderInterface`, or if you want to use your built-in db / eloquent provider, register a non-hashing class that implements `HasherInterface`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashing method used by Laravel generates a different hash each time (even for the same string).  You can read more about this in [Hashing for Laravel](http://laravel.io/topic/20/hashing-in-laravel).  As you can read, it doesn't hash both strings and compare them, instead it uses the unhashed string to compare with the hash.

If you really do want to do this you'll need to implement your own Auth Provider and a different hashing algorithm that allows you to compare hashes.

If you're concerned about security you should consider HTTPS so that secure details (including passwords) are never sent in plain text.

Answer (score 3):

You can login the user manually

```
$user = User::find($id);

if ($user->password == Request::getPassword()) {
    Auth::login($user->id);
}
```

Comment: It should not be possible to compare generated hashes since they're different every time.  See my answer for a link explaining why they're different.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't be hashing the password before you are sending them.  How are you going to be able to hash the password properly prior to sending it without the salt?  If you have access to the salt before sending the password then why are you using an API?

If you are worried about security of passing an un-hashed password, then you should be using SSL to ensure a secure transfer of data.

Don't consider an API any different then using a web page -- and you don't salt passwords before you submit a form on a website, instead if you need that level of security you rely on https / SSL.